# Understanding proof of: Let $v$ be a vertex in a 2-connected graph $G$. Show that $v$ has a neighbor u such that $G - u - v$ is connected.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the following proof:
[image]

Every connected graph has a spanning tree, and since $G-v$ is connected it must contain a spanning tree $T$. However why is it easy to see that every leaf of $T$ has an edge to $v$ in $G$?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$T$ here is not a spanning tree. It is the smallest connected subgraph of $G \setminus v$ that contains the neighbors of $v$. (It might not contain all the vertices of $G \setminus v$, i.e. it might not span $G \setminus v$.)

Comment: Still, why is it clear that every leaf of H has an edge to v?

Comment: @Robin Another way to say this sentence is "every leaf of $T$ is in $U$." If this were not true, then there would be a leaf of $T$ that is not in $U$; then you could remove this leaf from $T$ to get a strictly smaller subgraph that still contains all the vertices of $U$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, does this mean that for any neighbhor $u$ of $v$, $G-v-u$ is connected? As our choice of $u$ is any leaf of $T$, which is a neighbhor of $v$. So then the theorem should be for all neighbhor $u$ of $v$, $G-u-v$ is connected?

Comment: @mathnoob The choice of $u$ is any leaf of $T$, which is a neighbor of $v$. But not all neighbors of $v$ are leaves of $T$.

Comment: But then how do we know that $C$ does not contain any neighbhor of $v$? Also by construction of $T$, $U$, which is the set of neighbhor of $v$ is in $V(T)$ So that means $T$ contains all neighbhors of $v$?

Comment: @mathnoob Yes, $T$ contains all neighbors of $v$, but not all vertices of $T$ are leaves.